# Why doesn't this switch statement successfully replace the characters of the String to solve this Javascript Algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, switch-statement

**Question**

Convert the characters &, <, >, " (double quote), and ' (apostrophe), in a string to their corresponding HTML entities.

**My Code**

```js
function convertHTML(str) {
  
  let tempArr = ['a'];
  let newArr = [];
  let regex = /[&<>"']/


str.split('')
  .forEach((item)=>{
      switch(item){
    case '&': tempArr[0] = '&amp';
    break;
    case '<': tempArr[0] = '&lt';
    break;
    case '>': tempArr[0] = '&gt';
    break;
    case '"': tempArr[0] = '&quot';
    break;
    case "'": tempArr[0] = '&apos';
    break;
  }
    if(regex.test(item)==true){
      item.replace(item, tempArr[0])
    }
    newArr.push(item);
  })

    return newArr;


}

console.log(convertHTML("Dolce & Gabbana"));
```

By my understanding of the code, this should work. So there must be something wrong with my understanding. (I would still have to join the array, but the replace is not working).

Comment: Use map instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doing nothing:

```
item.replace(item, tempArr[0])
```

`replace` does not alter any of its arguments. It returns a new string which you don't use.

But since `item` is just that one character, you should just assign the replacement for it:

```
item = tempArr[0]
```

NB: I have no idea why you use `tempArr` as an array, since it never has anything else than 1 element, so it could just as well be a string.

Here is a simpler way to get the job done:

```js
function convertHTML(str) {
  let entity = {
      "'": "&apos",
      "&": "&amp;",
      "<": "&lt;",
      ">": "&gt;",
      '"': "&quot",
  };
  return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, item => entity[item]);
}

console.log(convertHTML("Dolce & Gabbana"));
```

Comment: what you do is quite inspirational. I hope that if I get to your point of understanding, I will do the same to help people.